# Hadoop copyFromLocal problem wit copying directory

Tags: hadoop

I'd like to copy whole local directory with some subdirectories and files to HDFS. HDFS already contains the root directory and some subdirectories with files. I just want to add newer files from local directory.

```
Local directory /www/hitlogfetcher/logs/:
day=20--hour=00/files.....
  |-hour=01/files.....
  |-hour=02/files....

HDFS /hitlogfetcher-test/:
day==20--hour=00/files
   |-hour=01/
```

When I used command:
    hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /www/hitlogfetcher/logs/* /hitlogfetcher-test/
I received error message:

```
Target /hitlogfetcher-test/day=20 is a directory
```

- day=20 is a directory that contains some subdirectories and files

So I would like to copy files from directory hour=01 and then cpy directory hour=02 and its files.

Is it possible by using hadoop shell commands or another way?

Answer (score 0):

The copyFromLocal command will upload directories recursively by default, so you don't need the "*":

```
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /www/hitlogfetcher/logs/  /hitlogfetcher-test/
                                                  ^
```

Comment: The command without "*" is OK, of course. But it doesn't work correctly for me.

Comment: This command will copy directory logs/ as well. I need just day=20/hour=02/*.
I would like copyFromLocal to behave just as cp from Linux:
cp -r /www/hitlogfetcher/logs/* /hitlogfetcher-test/