# rsync files to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, rsync

I have 6 servers and each contains a lot of logs. I'd like to put these logs to hadoop fs via rsync. Now I'm using fuse and rsync writes directly to fuse-mounted fs /mnt/hdfs.
But there is a big problem. After about a day, the fuse deamon occupies 5 GB of RAM and it's not possible to do anything with mounted fs. So I have to remount fuse and everything is OK, but just for some time.
Rsync command is

```
rsync --port=3360 -az --timeout=10 --contimeout=30 server_name::ap-rsync/archive /mnt/hdfs/logs
```

Rsync produces error message after some time:

```
rsync error: timeout in data send/receive (code 30) at io.c(137) [sender=3.0.7]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (498784 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [receiver=3.0.7]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (498658 bytes received so far) [generator]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [generator=3.0.7]
```

Answer (score 5):

Fuse-hdfs does not support `O_RDWR` and `O_EXCL`, so rsync get a EIO error.
If you want to use rsync with fuse-hdfs, it is needed to patch the code.
You have two ways to modify, each one is OK.  I recommend to use the second method.

1. patch fuse-hdfs, it could be find in hadoop.

   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-861
2. patch rsync (version 3.0.8).

   ```
   diff -r rsync-3.0.8.no_excl/syscall.c rsync-3.0.8/syscall.c

   234a235,252
   > #if defined HAVE_SECURE_MKSTEMP && defined HAVE_FCHMOD && (!defined HAVE_OPEN64 || defined HAVE_MKSTEMP64)
   >   {
   >       int fd = mkstemp(template);
   >       if (fd == -1)
   >           return -1;
   >       if (fchmod(fd, perms) != 0 && preserve_perms) {
   >           int errno_save = errno;
   >           close(fd);
   >           unlink(template);
   >           errno = errno_save;
   >           return -1;
   >       }
   > #if defined HAVE_SETMODE && O_BINARY
   >       setmode(fd, O_BINARY);
   > #endif
   >       return fd;
   >   }
   > #else
   237c255,256
   <   return do_open(template, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, perms);
   ---
   >   return do_open(template, O_RDWR|O_EXCL|O_CREAT, perms);
   > #endif
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly is the question, but I think to properly solve the generic problem of moving logs to HDFS you may consider using Flume: https://github.com/cloudera/flume
- http://www.cloudera.com/resource/hw10_flume_reliable_distributed_streaming_log_collection

Comment: Flume is pretty heavy weight and has a bunch of dependencies. So while it will do a terrific job of moving logs, it will not be that easy to setup.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at flume. But I want transfer gzipped log files with their subdirectories. When I tried it transfered files were not complete. Text files were OK but gzipped files not.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /path/to/logs hdfs:///path/to/logs/$DATE](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.19.2/hdfs_shell.html#copyFromLocal). No need for rsync since you're putting the logs in dated directories. No need for FUSE either, which is good for prototyping but unreliable as you have seen.

Comment: This option was my first attempt how to avoid using rsyng directly to hadoop fuse. 
First I rsynced new files to a local directory and then I used hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal. But I had a problem with copying to hdfs.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449562/hadoop-copyfromlocal-problem-wit-copying-directory
If it were possible to use this command it would be great.